# A lambda function trigger on deleting a AWS cognito user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm very new to AWS cognito. I want to send a mail on deleting a user from AWS cognito user pool. I learnt that there is a list of predefined event trigger sources for various user actions such as sign up, sign in, password change etc., but, there is no such event trigger sources for deleting a user. I found few similar questions posted and saw that using cognito sync trigger was recommended and when I tried to follow that, it asked me to select a cognito identity pool to proceed further but there is no identity pool used in my project.
Kindly let me know how can I trigger a lambda function on deleting a cognito user.

Comment: Is your `cognito` setup with `aws-amplify` ?

Comment: No, we don't have cognito setup with aws-amplify

Comment: ok, and do your backend has access to the AWS account ? or just only `cognito` is used for Auth ?

Comment: I just found that aws-amplify is used in a angular app as an import statement. Auth from aws-amplify is imported and is used to call cognito services like Auth.signIn , Auth.confirmSignUp etc.,

Comment: yes, `amplify` is a backend service with many different features. You can also use `API Gateway` for triggering a lambda function which will send the email

Answer (score 0):

Identity pools are used for giving temporary access to you `AWS Resources/Services`, you can refer the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html)

> Amazon Cognito identity pools (federated identities) enable you to create unique identities for your users and federate them with identity providers. With an identity pool, you can obtain temporary, limited-privilege AWS credentials to access other **AWS services**.

Since your backend is not using any `AWS resource`, you can use `AWS API Gateway` for creating an `endpoint` which can be hit to trigger the `lambda function`, as `Auth` provider of the api you can use `cognito`. Here is the [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html)

Comment: It's a design choice, whether you want to have an extra `API` or just use `Cognito Sync Trigger` for triggering the lambda. Please feel free to accept if you feel the answer helped.

Comment: To use cognito sync trigger, having identity pool is necessary right. Pls don't mind my silly questions as I'm very new to this.

Comment: Yes, you have to create, you can [refer this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-events.html)